# Android crashes related to frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaCodec.cpp:311 CHECK(format->findString("mime", &mime)) failed

Tags: c++, android-mediacodec

Quite some crashes share the same thread:

```
frameworks/base/media/jni/android_media_MediaCodec.cpp:311 CHECK(format->findString("mime", &mime)) failed.
```

The details vary. They are still rare relatively for an app with hundreds of thousands of active users.
The following is one of them:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000007848c  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #01  pc 0x000000000055dbf4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2308)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000013988  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000006e44  /system/lib64/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+336)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000040028  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android::JMediaCodec::configure(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&, android::sp<android::IGraphicBufferProducer> const&, android::sp<android::ICrypto> const&, android::sp<android::hardware::cas::native::V1_0::IDescrambler> const&, int)+488)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000043a40  /system/lib64/libmedia_jni.so (android_media_MediaCodec_native_configure(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobjectArray*, _jobjectArray*, _jobject*, _jobject*, _jobject*, int)+588)
  #06  pc 0x0000000000239ab0  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+272)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000662c50  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.configure+1472)
  #08  pc 0x0000000000663944  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (android.media.MediaCodec.configure+68)
  #09  pc 0x0000000000133564  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+548)
  #10  pc 0x00000000001a8a78  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+200)
  #11  pc 0x0000000000318290  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376)
  #12  pc 0x000000000030e5bc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+996)
  #13  pc 0x00000000006833a8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+672)
  #14  pc 0x0000000000131594  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_quick+20)
```

All of the app's code related to MediaCodec is in try-catch blocks. This crash seems to be related to [MediaCodec.configure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec#configure(android.media.MediaFormat,%20android.view.Surface,%20android.media.MediaCrypto,%20int))

```
 _mfVideo = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/hevc", iImageWidth, iImageHeight);
 _mcVideoDecoder.configure(_mfVideo, _surface, null, 0);
```

or

```
 _mfVideo = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat("video/avc", iImageWidth, iImageHeight);
 _mcVideoDecoder.configure(_mfVideo, _surface, null, 0);
```

or

```
_mfAudio = MediaFormat.createAudioFormat("audio/mp4a-latm", iClockRateAudio, _siChannelNo);
_mcAudioDecoder.configure(_mfAudio, null, null, 0);
```

In summary, the following are the only three mimes used:

- "video/hevc"
- "video/avc"
- "audio/mp4a-latm"

They work fine most of the time.

Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes of these crashes and any tip on how to remedy them?